# How to load images from a directory and move them

Tags: python

I am kind of new to python and I am trying to make a bot, I wanted to know the simplest way to get images from my files onto a screen in python. I want to load 2 images from my computer to pycharm/IDE python, both of the images are in a file ->
Path: `C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\Desktop\bot_Images` .

i also wanted to use `turtle.write("Text Here", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))` to put text on the screen.

Then i would like to know how to move the text to be inside another image called text_box.png i need both images to be on the same turtle screen.  [How i would like it to be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFPsa.png)

i would also like to know how to move the text box.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a image with turtle you want first initialize screen then use `turtle.addshape()` to add the image into turtle's shape list.

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

bot_image_path = "<Absolute Path To Your Image>" # Note: The image must be gif format
screen.addshape(bot_image_path)  # Add image to turtle's shape list
turtle.shape(bot_image_path)  # Draw shape
```

To write the text within the textbox, you can use `turtle.goto` to move the cursor to the textbox's position and write the text.

Comment: Thanks sqz i used your code then did
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.write("My Text", font=("Arial", 40, "normal"))